# Adding legend for specific ranges not for discrete values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, legend, mapping

I want to add legend for a QGIS proportional symbol map rangewise. That is my data ranges from 57000-630000. So I want the legend as:

```
57000-60000,
60500-70000,
74000-79000,
81000-87000,
90000-94000,
115000-124000,
125000-226000,
250000-290000,
293000-300000,
350000-373000,
374000-390000,
600000-630000
```

But in QGIS I am only able to add the legend for a particular value like 57000, 69000. Is there any way to add the legend for ranges?

On adding the legend it displays this:
[image]

Layer panel screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Open "Layer Styling <kbd>F7</kbd>" panel.
2. Select "Graduated".
3. Select the related field.
4. Set "Method" to "Size".
5. Change number of "Classes".
6. Double-click on "Values" you want to change and change.

When you change a lower or upper value, previous and next symbol values are updated, too, accordingly. I am unsure if there is a way to leave a space between numbers of consecutive symbol values, like symbol1:10-30, symbol2:60-100.

[image]

Comment: It worked,but the legend is not displaying in the map,how to display it?

Comment: @Letitbe What do you mean by "in the map"? "Layers" panel displays the legend. https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xE4.png

Comment: but when I try to make a map with these legend,on adding the legend the circles are not displaying in the legend and also the details of all layers in the map is displaying in the legend.I will add the screenshot of it in the question section.Sorry the added screenshot does not capture the bottomportiopn of the legend which displays the layer information.

Comment: @Letitbe I see, you mean the legend  in the layout page.

Comment: Yes, can you help me to figure out that. sorry I am new to QGIS,I am not familiar with the technical terms in it.

Comment: Do you see the symbols in "Layers" panel as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xE4.png)? The Legend is created as expected in my layout page -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h8JG.png

Comment: No my layer panel just displays the layers of the map,it is different as yours,it is not displaying symbols.I will add the screenshot of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123340/discussion-between-letitbe-and-kadir-sahbaz).

Comment: When expanding 20cities - Copy layer in Layers panel, are there any symbols?
I don't encounter an error as you do. So, I have no other solution that I can offer you.

Comment: @ Kadir Şahbaz Yes when expanding the layers symbols are showing,but not in legend added in layout page as yours.